# Cleanly combine year and month columns to single date column with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, dataframe

I have data that looks like this:

```
+----+------+-------+
| ID | YEAR | MONTH |
+----+------+-------+
| A  | 2017 |     1 |
| B  | 2017 |     2 |
| C  | 2017 |     3 |
| D  | 2017 |     4 |
| E  | 2017 |     5 |
| F  | 2017 |     6 |
+----+------+-------+
```

I want to add a new column called `DATE` which store the a new column made up of a date object of the `YEAR` and `MONTH` columns.  Something like this:

```
+----+------+-------+------------+
| ID | YEAR | MONTH |    DATE    |
+----+------+-------+------------+
| A  | 2017 |     1 | 2017-01-01 |
| B  | 2017 |     2 | 2017-02-01 |
| C  | 2017 |     3 | 2017-03-01 |
| D  | 2017 |     4 | 2017-04-01 |
| E  | 2017 |     5 | 2017-05-01 |
| F  | 2017 |     6 | 2017-06-01 |
+----+------+-------+------------+
```

I used the following code to create the column, but was wondering if there's a cleaner 'Pythonic' one-liner. Something along the lines of `df['DATE']=date(df.year, df.month, 1)`.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date


ID  = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
YEAR = [2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017]
MONTH = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]


df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ID, 'YEAR': YEAR, 'MONTH': MONTH})


DATE = []
for y, m in zip(df.YEAR, df.MONTH):
    DATE.append(date(y, m, 1))


df['DATE'] = DATE
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**Option 1**
Pass a dataframe slice with 3 columns - `YEAR`, `MONTH`, and `DAY`, to `pd.to_datetime`.

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['YEAR', 'MONTH']].assign(DAY=1))
df

  ID  MONTH  YEAR       DATE
0  A      1  2017 2017-01-01
1  B      2  2017 2017-02-01
2  C      3  2017 2017-03-01
3  D      4  2017 2017-04-01
4  E      5  2017 2017-05-01
5  F      6  2017 2017-06-01
```

---

**Option 2**
String concatenation, with `pd.to_datetime`.

```
pd.to_datetime(df.YEAR.astype(str) + '/' + df.MONTH.astype(str) + '/01')

0   2017-01-01
1   2017-02-01
2   2017-03-01
3   2017-04-01
4   2017-05-01
5   2017-06-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Note that `year`, `month`, and `day` are special strings that pandas looks for. If your columns are named something else (e.g., `start_year`), you'll have to rename them before converting (`df.rename(columns={'start_year': 'year'})`).

Comment: The second method works without any exceptions.

Comment: Option 1 is a neat trick.

Comment: Don't forget the `inplace=True` flag or else the column renamer won't actually rename the column but return a copy (not shown in @kris comment)

Comment: For me Option 1 shows error
```ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [month,year] is missing```